# How to get consistent white balance on a 3 photo stack?

Tags: white-balance, image-stacking, 360-panorama

I have a 3-photo stack - the same photo done with -2, 0, +2 EV, and want the same white balance on each of the photos.

Photos will be used to construct a 360 degree panorama, 4x3 photos stack = 12 photos per panorama.

Is it possible with ImageMagick or other free tool, or do I need pro software?

I want to fix EXIF too, but it is optional.

Comment: The obvious answer here is "take them with the same white balance". Could you expand your question to explain why that's not an option?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Or shoot RAW files and apply the same WB to all of them in post.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is indeed to shoot with a fixed white balance or to shoot in RAW.

However, PTAssmbler (http://www.tawbaware.com/ptasmblr.htm) offers the ability match white balances. At $45 it's not free, but still is reasonable. On the whole I prefer it to Hugin, but not by a tremendous margin.

Comment: Price maybe is good but tools is not popular.

Comment: True, but I still like it:) And it does offer some features that Hugin lacks.

Comment: @Chameleon - I've used PTAssembler for years and in the Panoramic-Photo-Stitching world it's fairly well known - In part because of the application's developer, Max Lyons', images are well done.  Apple even used one of his gigapixel images for one of their events 5 years ago or so.

Comment: Time to try this program.